# Finding differential equation given general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand how it would be possible to find the differential equation associated with this general solution because differentiation doesn't eliminate constants. Is there another method here; what am I missing?
$$
y_h(t)=C_1\cos(2t)+C_2\sin(2t)+C_3e^{2t}
$$
Attempt: Looking at the roots of the characteristic equation $(2i, -2i,$ and $2)$, this problem became a lot easier. The characteristic equation is then $(m-2i)(m+2i)(m-2)=0.$

Comment: Perhaps you can recognize some terms as a homogeneous part and other part as non-homogeneous ? For example, can you think of a differential equation that has the solution $y(t) = C_1 \cos 2t + C_2 \sin 2t$ ? Perhaps you can differentiate that a bunch of times and see what you obtain.

Comment: Yes I believe the differential equation with that solution is y''+4y=0 and I see below how a system of y, y', and y'' can lead to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Form the characteristicv polynomial:
$$(r^2+4)(r-2)=0$$
$$r^3-2r^2+4r-8=0$$
From the differential equation from this now:
$$y'''-2y''+4y'-8y=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\cases{
y(t) = c_1 \cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)+c_3 e^{2t}\\
y'(t) = -2c_1\sin(2t)+2c_2\cos(2t)+2c_3 e^{2t}\\
y''(t) = -4c_1\cos(2t)-4c_2\sin(2t)+4c_3 e^{2t}
}
$$

now solving for $c_3$ we get

$$
c_3 = \frac 18 e^{-2t}\left(y''(t)+4y(t)\right)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$

but $c_3$ is a generic constant so $c_3'=0$ or

$$
\frac 18 e^{-2t}\left(y'''(t)-2y''(t)+4y'(t)-8y(t)\right)=0
$$

or finally

$$
y'''(t)-2y''(t)+4y'(t)-8y(t) = 0
$$

NOTE

From

$$
\cases{
y(t) = c_1 \cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)+c_3 e^{2t}\\
y''(t) = -4c_1\cos(2t)-4c_2\sin(2t)+4c_3 e^{2t}
}
$$

multiplying by $4$ the first equation and adding both we obtain easily $(*)$

Comment: Thank you! I see how setting up the system with differentiated equations is a more robust way to do this type of problem. Does anyone have a reference or tip on solving such a system. It appears a lot more daunting than simply solving for c3 here.

Comment: Please. See the attached note.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.In the third degree $m$ polynomial,just plug in the corresponding derivative order.